# Office 2013 JavaScript API - Remove Table Filter Buttons

Tags: excel, office-addins, office-js, office-2013

I am not been able to remove Table Filter button
 [image],
I am using the below code

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(sampleDataForExcel, { tableOptions: { filterButton: false } },
            function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    app.showNotification('Could not insert sample data',
                        'Please choose a different selection range.');
                } else {
                    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync(
                        Office.BindingType.Table, { id: "myBinding" },
                        function (asyncResult) {
                            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                                app.showNotification('Error binding data');
                            } else {
                                window.location.href = '../index.html';
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, but it is working fine on my machine using the following sample:

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(myTable,
    {
        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table,
        tableOptions: { filterButton: false }
    }
```